# Getting rid of "undefined" Typescript Error, React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, undefined

I am new to TypeScript configuration, but I was coding yesterday and wrapping the code block with an if checking if usersData made the "Object is possibly undefined" errors go away. Now I load the code up today and I have red squiggles ***everywhere*** that I did this, what changed? Is this not the correct way to handle undefined? The thing is my React application still runs, but my VSCode is littered in Errors, not warnings, so I was thinking this could just be my VSCode bugging out?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

ts.config

> `{
>     "extends": "./paths.json",
>     "compilerOptions": {
>       "target": "es5",
>       "lib": [
>         "dom",
>         "dom.iterable",
>         "esnext"
>       ],
>       "allowJs": true,
>       "skipLibCheck": true,
>       "sourceMap": true,
>       "esModuleInterop": true,
>       "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
>       "strict": true,
>       "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
>       "module": "esnext",
>       "moduleResolution": "node",
>       "resolveJsonModule": true,
>       "isolatedModules": true,
>       "noEmit": true,
>       "jsx": "react"
>     },
>     "include": [
>       "src",
>       "typings/fonts.d.ts"
>     ]
>   }`

Error

> `if (usersResponse) {
>               let finalData = usersResponse.map((singleUser: any) => {
>                   return (
>                       { label: '${singleUser.PreferredLastName}, ${singleUser.PreferredFirstName}', id: singleUser.UserID }
>                   );
>               });
>               setUsersData(finalData);
>           }`

[Error in Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3musS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share enough code to correctly determine (next please post full file or replicated snippet with the error) but I assume that typescript is not complying that `usersResponse` is not defined, but rather that it might be different than non-iterable instance.

let's assume you have this:

```
const userResponse = 'text'

const convertUserData = () => {
  if (userResponse) {
    userResponse.map(() => ...)
  }
}
```

You will hit an error as `userResponse` is not an array thus you need to type either `userResponse` correctly as "array of items" or expand the guard to

```
if (userResponse && Array.isArray(userResponse)) {
  ...
}
```